# Square root of 1 is (not) -1

Tags: fake-proofs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$i^2$ why is it $-1$ when you can show it is $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/i2-why-is-it-1-when-you-can-show-it-is-1)

I was thinking on the following line of thoughts:
$1 =  \sqrt{1} = \sqrt{-1 \cdot -1} = \sqrt{-1} \cdot \sqrt{-1} = i^2 = -1$

Of course this is not true, but I was wondering which step in this 'line of thoughts' is forbidden to make?

Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The incorrect step is the assumption that $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$

While this holds for nonnegative numbers, it does not hold for negative numbers. This has to do with the convention that $\sqrt 4 = 2$ instead of $-2$.

I should also note that this is a duplicate-post-in-idea, so it will probably be closed.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/i2-why-is-it-1-when-you-can-show-it-is-1) is almost an exact duplicate; others whose answers you may find helpful include [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/1-is-not-1-so-where-is-the-mistake) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84436/which-step-in-this-process-allows-me-to-erroneously-conclude-that-i-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{-1 \cdot -1}$ is not equal to $\sqrt{-1} \cdot \sqrt{-1}$. The formula $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is only valid when both $a,b$ are nonnegative real numbers.

Comment: Oke I did not no that rule. Thanks :)

Comment: *know​​​​​​​​​​